# Finding Max Values depending on Lookup Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Sale Invoices for bread, jam, etc. like this table.

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| Item  | Date   | Price |
+-------+--------+-------+
| Bread | 1-Dec  | 5     |
+-------+--------+-------+
| Jam   | 1-Dec  | 5     |
+-------+--------+-------+
| Bread | 8-Dec  | 6     |
+-------+--------+-------+
| Jam   | 8-Dec  | 4     |
+-------+--------+-------+
| Bread | 15-Dec | 4     |
+-------+--------+-------+
| Jam   | 15-Dec | 7     |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

I want the highest price date for each item like

```
+-------+--------+---------------+
| Item  | Date   | Highest Price |
+-------+--------+---------------+
| Bread | 8-Dec  | 6             |
+-------+--------+---------------+
| Jam   | 15-Dec | 7             |
+-------+--------+---------------+
```

It is like finding Max Values depending on Lookup Values. It is very much like Group By and Max in SQL. How do I do it in excel? I've tried index match and also googling. Nothing helps. Please help me.

Comment: You can have a look at Pivot Table. It will serve your purpose.

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done through a pivot table:

[image]

- Select your data.
- Insert a pivot table.
- In your case use "Item" & "Date" as rows.
- In your case use "Price" as value.
- Then click "Price" and under it's field settings choose "Max".
- Then in the pivot table itself right any date, click "Filter" > "Top Ten" and make that top 1 based on the max price.

---

There are many ways to do this through formulae, but if one has Excel O365 it can be done through one single formula, for example:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1,2,3},TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A7)),TRANSPOSE(MINIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7),C2:C7,MAXIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7)))),TRANSPOSE(MAXIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7)))))
```

Or:

```
=FILTER(A2:C7,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7),0))*LET(X,MAXIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C7,MAXIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7))))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B7,MINIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7),C2:C7,X),0))))
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the mail problem is almost solved. Is there any way to display in pivot as the order of Item, Max price and Date?

Comment: @PhyoMinYu, I don't understand. If you have another question feel free to open one on SO and explain your issue.

Comment: My bad. The question is already solved. But, I need to display Values column before Rows columns in Pivot like Item, Max Price, Date. It is actually another problem. Sorry.